# Recommended Laptop!

Tags: compatibility

Hello everyone I'm currently planning to purchase a new notebook and of-course gonna install Ubuntu but i need to know the best laptops compatible with Linux.
I don't care about high graphics cards (Intel HD-4000) will be enough for me and what's more important the network adapters (Ethernet, WiFi) would work fine because i remember had bad time with the previous Broadcom adapter.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You may want to rework your question. Visit [the help section](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). "Shopping Recommendations" are not really a good fit here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a shopping recommendation which as per the help-center/FAQ is not really an distinct enough question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great place to start looking -> ([Ubuntu Certified Hardware Listing](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)).